# Trying to Add Insert Row to Footer in GridView ASP.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to give the user the ability to create a new record from the footer row and my event handler doesn't seem to be working... or maybe I'm going at this all wrong.

The insert button that I enabled in the gridview doesn't work either...checkout the site at http://aisched.engr.oregonstate.edu/admin/courses.aspx

Here is my code in front and behind:

```
public partial class admin_courses : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public Table table;
ListDictionary listValues = new ListDictionary();
TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox(); //Name
TextBox textBox2 = new TextBox(); //CR
TextBox textBox3 = new TextBox(); //CourseNum
TextBox textBox4 = new TextBox(); //Dept



protected void Page_Init()
{

}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Footer) return; //Escape if not footer

    textBox1.ID = "name";
    textBox1.Width = 250;
    textBox2.ID = "credit_hours";
    textBox2.Width = 25;
    textBox3.ID = "dept";
    textBox3.Width = 30;
    textBox4.ID = "class";
    textBox4.Width = 25;

    LinkButton add = new LinkButton();
    add.ID = "add";
    add.Text = "Add course";
    add.CommandName = "add";
    add.Click += new EventHandler(add_Click);

    e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(textBox1);
    e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(textBox2);
    e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(textBox3);
    e.Row.Cells[4].Controls.Add(textBox4);
    e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(add);

}


public void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("you Clicked Add Course!");

        if (textBox1.Text != null && textBox2.Text != null && textBox3.Text != null && textBox4.Text != null) {
            listValues.Add("name", textBox1.Text);
            listValues.Add("credit_hours", textBox2.Text);
            listValues.Add("dept", textBox4.Text); //For Visual
            listValues.Add("class", textBox3.Text);
        }
        LinqDataSource1.Insert(listValues);
        Response.Redirect("~/admin/courses.aspx");
}
```

}

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/admin.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="courses.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin_courses" Title="OSU Aisched | Admin - Courses" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="admin_nav_links" Runat="Server">
<ul id="main">
    <li><a href="overview.aspx">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="users.aspx">Users</a></li>
    <li class="current_page_item"><a href="courses.aspx">Courses</a></li>
    <li><a href="programs.aspx">Programs</a></li>
    <li><a href="sections.aspx">Sections</a></li>
    <li><a href="import.aspx">Import</a></li>
    <li><a href="logs.aspx">Logs</a></li>
</ul>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
ContextTypeName="DataClassesDataContext" EnableDelete="True" 
EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" TableName="courses">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
<h1><a>Courses</a></h1>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="course_id" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" 
    BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
    CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" AllowSorting="True" ShowFooter="True"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
<RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="course_id" HeaderText="ID" 
        ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="course_id" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="credit_hours" HeaderText="CR" 
        SortExpression="credit_hours" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="dept" HeaderText="Dept" SortExpression="dept" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="class" HeaderText="#" SortExpression="class" />
    <asp:CommandField DeleteImageUrl="~/media/delete.png" ShowDeleteButton="True" 
        ShowEditButton="True" ShowInsertButton="True"/>
</Columns>
<FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
<PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>


<br />
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Target="~/admin/addCourse.aspx"  Enabled="true"NavigateUrl="~/admin/addCourse.aspx" Text="Add New course"></asp:HyperLink>
<br />

</form>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: You should always bind event handlers in init even if you create the button in Init and then add the button in rowdatabound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect (or at least I certainly hope) there's a better way to do this, but try this:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource runat="server" ID="LinqDataSource1" ContextTypeName="Courses.DataClassesDataContext" TableName="Courses" EnableDelete="True" EnableUpdate="True" EnableInsert="True" />
<h1>
    <a>
        Courses</a></h1>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="course_id"
    DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None"
    BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" AllowSorting="True" 
    ShowFooter="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="course_id" HeaderText="course_id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="course_id"
            InsertVisible="False" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" >
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="credit_hours" SortExpression="credit_hours">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("credit_hours") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("credit_hours") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="HoursTextBox" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="dept" SortExpression="dept">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dept") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dept") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="DeptTextBox" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="class" SortExpression="class">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("class") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("class") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="ClassTextBox" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                    Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                    Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                    Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete"
                    Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="AddLinkButton" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add" CausesValidation="true" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                // We are in a Postback so check to see if the AddLinkButton was clicked
                String eventTarget = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString();

                if (eventTarget.EndsWith("addlinkbutton",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    // We are adding a new row so build a ListDictionary with the controls from the footer row
                    ListDictionary values = new ListDictionary();

                    values.Add("name", ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("NameTextBox")).Text);
                    values.Add("credit_hours", ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("HoursTextBox")).Text);
                    values.Add("dept", ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("DeptTextBox")).Text);
                    values.Add("class", ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ClassTextBox")).Text);

                    // Pass the ListDictionary to the data source to send off to the database
                    LinqDataSource1.Insert(values);

                    // Refresh the grid so it shows the row we just added
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

I couldn't make it work without writing code manually to do the Insert. Handling the AddLinkButton_Click event in the Page_Load event by examining the EventTarget hidden field to see if it ends with 'addlinkbutton' feels quite wrong, but it works.

Comment: That worked great Phil - how can I set the columns to auto-resize so they are not way wider than they need to be/

Comment: You pretty much can't - your options are either: in the markup set the width attribute for each control, or create a CSS class with the width set and then set the CSSClass attribute for each control. Sorry but there's not really a better way to do this!

Comment: Ok, and if I wanted to add a selected row I would just put the following below the "Delete"?

When I tried to handle the select in my code behind I only had access to the "id" when referenced via datagrid.row.cells[0]... but none of the other fields...?

    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server"         CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Select"
                    Text="Select"></asp:LinkButton>

Answer (score 1):

A Sample pseudo code which can add from grid view footer, Initially data's are saved under View State, Using button click event to check the ViewState and insert the new data to the table.

aspx code

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gvUser" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" OnRowDataBound="gvUser_RowDataBound"
    OnRowCommand="gvUser_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="gvUser_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gvUser_RowEditing" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        No Data Found
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Details" HeaderStyle-Width="25%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCourse" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Details") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDetails" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" CssClass="form-control" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="user Check One" HeaderStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgCheckOne" runat="server" Width="20" Height="20" ImageUrl='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("CheckOne").ToString())==false) ? "" : "../Contents/Images/tick.svg" %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>

            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCheckOne" runat="server" CssClass="i-checks" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HR Rec." HeaderStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgCheckTwo" runat="server" Width="20" Height="20" ImageUrl='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("CheckTwo").ToString())==false) ? "" : "../Contents/Images/tick.svg" %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>

            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCheckTwo" runat="server" CssClass="i-checks" />
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Wrap="true" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="5%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/Contents/Images/pencil.svg" Width="20" Height="20"
                    ToolTip="Edit"></asp:ImageButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="5%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/Contents/Images/remove.svg" Width="20" Height="20"
                    ToolTip="Delete"></asp:ImageButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnAdd" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="Add" ImageUrl="~/Contents/Images/add.svg" Width="20" Height="20" 
                    ToolTip="Add"></asp:ImageButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Server side code

```
protected void gvUser_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        List<TableOne> controlDetails = new List<TableOne>();
        controlDetails = dc.TableOne.Where(condition).ToList();
        controlDetails.Insert(0, new TableOne() { ID = 0, Name = "Select Details" });
        DropDownList ddlDetails = (e.Row.FindControl(ddlDetails) as DropDownList);
        ddlDetails.DataSource = controlDetails;
        ddlDetails.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddlDetails.DataValueField = "ID";
        ddlDetails.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void gvUser_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
            int RowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
            DataTable dtUserDetails = (DataTable)ViewState["gvUser"];
            DataRow dr = dtUserDetails.Rows[RowIndex];
            dr.Delete();
            gvUser.Rows[RowIndex].Visible = false;
        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {
            DropDownList ddlDetails = (DropDownList)((GridView)sender).FooterRow.FindControl("ddlDetails");
            CheckBox CheckOne = (CheckBox)((GridView)sender).FooterRow.FindControl("CheckOne");
            CheckBox CheckTwo = (CheckBox)((GridView)sender).FooterRow.FindControl("CheckTwo");

            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
            int RowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;

            DataTable dtUserDetails = (DataTable)ViewState["gvUser"];
            DataRow dr = dtUserDetails.Rows[RowIndex];
            ddlDetails.SelectedValue = dr["DetailID"].ToString();
            CheckOne.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["CheckOne"]);
            CheckTwo.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["CheckTwo"]);
            dr.Delete();
        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "Add")
        {
            DropDownList ddlDetails = (DropDownList)((GridView)sender).FooterRow.FindControl("ddlDetails");
            CheckBox CheckOne = (CheckBox)((GridView)sender).FooterRow.FindControl("CheckOne");
            CheckBox CheckTwo = (CheckBox)((GridView)sender).FooterRow.FindControl("CheckTwo");

            if (ViewState["gvUser"] != null)
            {
                DataTable existingTable = (DataTable)ViewState["gvUser"];
                existingTable.Rows.Add(0, Convert.ToInt32(hdnUserID.Value), 0, ddlDetails.SelectedItem.Value, ddlDetails.SelectedItem.Text, CheckOne.Checked, CheckTwo.Checked);
                ViewState["gvUser"] = existingTable;
                gvUser.DataSource = existingTable;
                gvUser.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                DataTable dtUsers = new DataTable();
                dtUsers.Columns.Add("ID");
                dtUsers.Columns.Add("UserID");
                dtUsers.Columns.Add("DetailsID");
                dtUsers.Columns.Add("Details");
                dtUsers.Columns.Add("CheckOne");
                dtUsers.Columns.Add("CheckTwo");
                dtUsers.Rows.Add(0, Convert.ToInt32(hdnUserID.Value), 0, ddlDetails.SelectedItem.Value, ddlDetails.SelectedItem.Text, CheckOne.Checked, CheckTwo.Checked);
                ViewState["gvUser"] = dtUsers;
                gvUser.DataSource = dtUsers;
                gvUser.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}

//dummy function to avoid runtime grid error
protected void gvCandidateJD_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

}
//dummy function to avoid runtime grid error
protected void gvCandidateJD_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (ViewState["gvUser"] != null)
    {
    TableOne userInfo = null;
    List<TableOne> userDetails = new List<TableOne>();
    DataTable userSpecificDetails = (DataTable)ViewState["gvUser"];
    for (int i = 0; i < userSpecificDetails.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        userInfo = new TableOne();
        userInfo.UserID = UserID; //supply value
        foreach (DataColumn col in userSpecificDetails.Columns)
        {
            switch (col.ColumnName)
            {
                case "DetailsID":
                    userInfo.DetailsID = Convert.ToInt16(userSpecificDetails.Rows[i][col.ColumnName]);
                    break;
                case "CheckOne":
                    userInfo.CheckOne = Convert.ToBoolean(userSpecificDetails.Rows[i][col.ColumnName]);
                    break;
                case "CheckTwo":
                    userInfo.CheckTwo = Convert.ToBoolean(userSpecificDetails.Rows[i][col.ColumnName]);
                    break;
            }
        }
        userDetails.Add(userInfo);
    }
    if (userDetails.Count > 0)
    {
        dc.TableOne.InsertAllOnSubmit(userDetails);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
    }
 }
}
```