# Create a new row in the footer of a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view that that has some columns in it and then a `FooterStyle`

I would like to add a row underneath the footer.

Here is my GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="cartGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    ShowFooter="true" CssClass="cartTbl" onrowdatabound="cartGrid_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="cartGrid_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="cartGrid_RowCancelingEdit"
    onrowupdating="cartGrid_RowUpdating" EmptyDataText="There are no items in your cart.">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemNo" HeaderText="Item No." ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemDesc" HeaderText="Item Description" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" DataFormatString="{0:C}" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="qLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("numItems") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="qtb" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("numItems") %>' CssClass="qtb" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalItemPrice" HeaderText="Item Total" DataFormatString="{0:C}" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="orderID" ReadOnly="true" ControlStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="itemID" ReadOnly="true" ControlStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle CssClass="cartFooter" />
</asp:GridView>
```

How would I add a row underneath? I am assuming it would be in the code behind, but i am not sure what to do since this is my first time working with asp.net. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Also, please let me know if i am leaving anything helpful out. Like i said above, i am very new to all of this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to Add Insert Row to Footer in GridView ASP.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798424/trying-to-add-insert-row-to-footer-in-gridview-asp-net)

Comment: It does seem similar, I have seen some examples online and throughout SO, but I dont really understand what I am doing or what i would need to do in my instance. This is why i am posting anyway. I was hoping that someone would be able to explain to me so I can gain a better overall knowledge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add additional rows to the footer, you have to catch hold of the `OnRowDataBound` Event

```
protected void cartGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {

                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
                TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
                cell1.Text = "Add your your content here"; 
                cell1.ColumnSpan = 8; // You can change this. If you want different cells you can add as many cells as you need
                tableRow.Controls.Add(cell1);
                e.Row.NamingContainer.Controls.Add(tableRow);
                // You can add additional rows like this.
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like:

```
protected void GridView1_RowData(object sender,GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
   {
      TableRow tr = new TableRow();

      TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
      cell1.Text = "A Button";

      TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
      Button button = new Button();

      button.ID = "button1";
      button.Text = "Click me!";
      button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
      cell2.Controls.Add(button);

      e.Row.Cells.Clear();
      e.Row.Cells.Add(cell1);
      e.Row.Cells.Add(cell2);

    }    
}

protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   String text = e.ToString();
}
```